# Laravel Queue Getting Duplicate Values

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am using laravel queue to get laters record of users

If two users use the same functaion at same time , the values get replicated

this is my code on controller

```
.......
SendInvitation::dispatch($email,$name,$nhs_number,$appInfo,$userInfo)->onQueue('high');
........
```

SendInvitation on quaue code

```
public function handle()
    {
        try {

        $user = User::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
      
        if($user != null){
            $enu_id = $user->invitation_id;

        }else{
            $enu_id = "EAA-0001-1";
        }
        $strArray = explode('-', $enu_id );
        $x = $strArray[0];
        if($strArray[0] == $x){
            if($strArray[1] < 9999){
                $get_id = $strArray[1];
                $e_id = $x.'-'.$get_id.'-';
            }else{
                $x++;
                $e_id = $x.'-0001-';
            }
        }else{
            if($strArray[1] < 9999){
                $x++;
                $get_id = $strArray[1];
                $e_id = $x.'-'.$get_id.'-';

            }else{
                $x++;
                $e_id = $x.'-0001-';
            }
        }
      }
    }
   ..........
```

I am getting the latest users $enu_id and

with a algorithum i am incrementing it

Its working fine....

my problem is if two users register at the same time the both gets the same id

it is wrong , that's why i have used Queaue

Is there any way not to stop overlapping until a queue gets over?

Thank you ....

Answer (score 0):

use Group By

Example:

```
myModel::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->groupBy('user_id')->first();
```